# Can't find a data in Firebase

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a controller in my ionic project that checks for the logged in user and display datas regarding that user.

However, I try to display a data that is link to this current user in the database. I tried that code but it doesn't display it :

```
.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope, $state, $cordovaOauth) {
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
    //Get logged in user credentials.
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var name, email, photoUrl, provider, description;

    console.log("User: " + JSON.stringify(user));
    if (user != null) {
        name = user.displayName;
        email = user.email;
        photoUrl = user.photoURL;
        provider = user.provider;
        uid = user.uid;
    }

    //Set Profile Image.
    $scope.profileImage = photoUrl;
    //Set Profile Name.
    $scope.profileName = name;
    //Set Profile email.
    $scope.profileEmail = email;
    //Set provider.
    $scope.provider = provider;

        var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        var accountRef = firebase.database().ref('accounts/' + userId);
        accountRef.on('value', function(account) {
        $scope.description = account.val().displayDescription;
        $scope.$apply();
    });
     }) ;
    });
```

But it is not displaying anything when I try {{description}}

In fact I try to have the account's line to find the "displayDescription" in my database linked to the current user, for example the user **-KOkwpzslw9NyUrTtvA7**

```
{
  "accounts" : {
    "-KOjv0LDdoWrc3uApvPi" : {
      "dateCreated" : "Tue Aug 09 2016 11:29:18 GMT-0400 (EDT)",
      "email" : "sdgsdgsd@tbteam.net",
      "provider" : "Facebook",
      "userId" : "FMXlUQZth5aehQLT2TKZZJZdJBh2"
    },
    "-KOkwpzslw9NyUrTtvA7" : {
      "dateCreated" : "Tue Aug 09 2016 16:16:52 GMT-0400 (EDT)",
      "displayDescription" : "no description",
      "email" : "sdgsdsddgd@yahoo.com",
      "provider" : "Facebook",
      "userId" : "F9Z7YhSlmAQqOH5FVjBSV2CkYZG3"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the accountRef.on function is not part of the digest cycle. Maybe you could try $scope.apply or using AngularFire.

Comment: Everything works if I just put var userId = '-KOkwpzslw9NyUrTtvA7'; I just try to have it so I have the current user automatically selected instead of writting this in the code you see :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi brother data from in that format account/userid/ then your data description you cant target like this . just simply grap data from that firebase.auth() function and save it to localstroge then you ca use it like the way you want